# How to Implement self join to obtain complete result using Linq c#?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, self-join

In my scenario I need to show all the employees whose manager id is @Id.

The hierarchy is like

```
Manager --- Employee
john --- smith
john --- sam
sam --- peru
sam --- karim
```

I am using linq and Entity Framework DB first.

I need to show all the employees under particular manager let take it john with `id = 2`

I apply 2 different queries but result is same ie it is showing only 1st hierarchy john is getting only 2 employees smith and sam but the employees inside sam must also be displayed are not retrieving..

Here is My code:

```
var lstAllUser = (List<Entities.User>)Session["AllUsers"];

int pID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlSelectedValue);

 //query 1 which i try first        
var lstSelectedEmployees1 = lstAllUser.Where(emp => emp.ManagerId == pID)
                                      .Select(emp => new { 
                                          EmployeeName = emp.UserDetail.Name, 
                                          ManagerName = emp.Manager.UserDetail.Name 
                                    }).ToList();

//query 2 
var lstSelectedEmployees = (from employee in lstAllUser
                            where employee.ManagerId == pID
                            join e1 in lstAllUser 
                            on employee.ManagerId equals e1.UserID
                            select new
                            {
                                ManagerName = e1.UserDetail.Name,
                                EmployeeName = employee.UserDetail.Name
                            }).ToList();


gvEmployeeManager.DataSource = lstSelectedEmployees;
gvEmployeeManager.DataBind();
```

Aspx is like;

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEmployeeManager" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="Vertical" CssClass="table table-striped">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeName" HeaderText="Employee" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ManagerName" HeaderText="Manager" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Help required!!

Comment: I can't get why `lstSelectedEmployees1` doesn't contain the data you want. Could you please post the definition of `Entities.User`? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you looking to get the entire heirachy back, or just the employees who report directly to the manager?

Comment: @JamesS i want entire hierarchy of employees who directly or indirectly report to the manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to get back all the employees reporting to a manager, and not just the ones directly reporting to them...

I don't think it will be possible to do this in a single query in LINQ. If you were using SQL Server (2005+) you could do a stored procedure that has a recursive Common Table Expression to do this (good example here: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) )

In C#/LINQ you'll be reduced to making multiple queries in a recursive code loop.
Heres an example

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetEmployeesAllLevels(int managerId)
{
  return GetEmployeesAllLevels(managerId, null);
}

private Dictionary<string, string> GetEmployeesAllLevels(int managerId, Dictionary<string, string> existingList)
{
  if (existingList == null) existingList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  var lstSelectedEmployees1 = lstAllUser.Where(emp => emp.ManagerId == managerId)
                                      .Select(emp => new { 
                                          EmployeeName = emp.UserDetail.Name, 
                                          ManagerName = emp.Manager.UserDetail.Name,
                                          UserId = emp.UserId 
                                    }).ToList();
  foreach(var emp in lstSelectedEmployees1)
  {
    existingList.Add(emp.EmployeeName, emp.ManagerName);
    existingList = GetEmployeesAllLevels(emp.UserId, existingList);
  }
  return existingList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks James i was was a bit confused but you resolved it. The recursive implementation always beat me.